# Insert into an array

Tags: php, arrays, list

`$alltext` variable contents this code inside:

```
<li>sometext</li><li>sometext</li>
<li>sometext</li><li>sometext</li>
```

**How do I get each `<li>...</li>` like an item of an array?**

Comment: If the HTML is not consistent (i.e.: can have other tags, attributes, etc.), you should use a DOM parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If each element is separated by a "new line", you could try:

```
$array = explode("\n",$alltext);
```

If they aren't, then:

```
$array = explode("</li>");

foreach($array as $k=>$v){
   $array[$k] = $v."</li>";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`$array = explode("\n", $alltext);`

It seems like you should have a better approach, though.

Answer (score 1):

If text is separated by **new line**, you could do this:

```
$arr = explode("\r\n", $alltext);
foreach($arr as $val){
  echo $val;
}
```

You would use `\n` if not under Windows.

Comment: I can't believe we both wrote almost the same, without even looking to each other's answer lol

Comment: @JCO: True with difference of new line chars :)

Comment: Yes, or he could use `PHP_EOL` like Dave said.

Answer (score 1):

Same answer as from @Sarfraz and @Dave Kiss, but crossplatform:

```
$listItems = explode(PHP_EOL, $alltext);
```

However, I agree with Dave Kiss when he says you should have a better approach (in software design).

Answer (score 0):

use explode function, use '\r\n' (linebreak) as a splitter